# Appium - reset.sh fails with error on "buildAndroidBootstrap" task on Mac

Tags: android, macos, selenium, path, appium

There could be a problem with my configuration, but I cannot figure out what's wrong. I am trying to get appium set up on a Mac for automated testing.

I am running this command:

```
./reset.sh --android --verbose
```

I always fail on this step:

```
* Building Android bootstrap
Running "buildAndroidBootstrap" task
Fatal error: Error finding ant binary, is it on your path?
---- FAILURE: reset.sh exited with status 1 ----
```

My path is as follows:

```
# Android and appium config
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

What am I doing wrong? Is my path missing something crucial? Googling to try and find out what the ant library is hasn't yielded me much results - what is it? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out ant is an apache tool, without which reset.sh will fail for Android. Installing ant with brew fixed the problem.